# Filtering Notes View UI programmatically in Notes Client

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

Is there a way to programmatically filter IBM Notes (Lotus Notes) view UI using complex criteria?

For example, if I want to let users specify criteria and then show results in notes view UI all documents with particular status and the particular manager name?

I am aware of [@SetViewInfo](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_SETVIEWINFO.html) formula, but as far as I understand it works with only one view column, and I don't understand, how can I apply a criteria, that contains more than one conditions inside, for example: Status="Completed" AND Manager="John Doe" ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this problem is to have a shared private on first use folder for the result set. You would use a form to gather the selection query or fulltext-query and put the documents in the result folder.